# Google Drive SDK - Does anybody know what the maximum length a file property value can be?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have scoured the documentation, but can't find anything.  I am getting 400 errors because the property length is too long.  What is the maximum length?

```
service.properties().update(
    fileId = fileId,
    propertyKey = 'test',
    visibility = 'PRIVATE',
    body = { 'key': 'test', 'value': 'shbvskdbvskdjbcvksjbvkjdfbvkjsbvdskbvkjsdbvskjdbvkdsjbvskjdbvsdkjbvskdjbvkdsjbvskjdbvskjdbvksjdbvkjdsbvkjdbsvksjdbvkjbsdvkjdbsvkjbsvkbjdvkjbsvkjbdskjbvsdkjbvkdsjbvsdkbvsdkjbvsdkjbv' }
).execute()
```

Update:  The actual value I am trying to write is the stat_info of the file.  However, I have compressed the pickled output and base64 encoded it like so:

```
>>> value = b64encode(compress(pickle.dumps(st_info), 9))
>>> print value
eNpLzi/mis9NzE6NLy5JLIkvSi0uzSnhKjDk0tDwNDY2tLDg8jSAIUMDAziJhEo0UgqMuILVi0vik0syc1PVuQqMQeLFYKGilNQyoIgJlx+EnwtVYopQkpSTn5xdDBQzgylKhCoyR1aUXZxZBRK0AKoqCSqw5NIDAItNNh4=
```

The length is currently: 168 chars.

Update 2:  For now, I have implemented a hack that divides the string up into 20 16 byte chunks.  These seem to be small enough to be written as properties.  I have used a generator for chunking, generating indexed keys.  It's not pretty and it's really slow, given the number of connections it's having to make.  I may have to park these changes and go back to using the description field.

Comment: I implemented properties using the description field long before the properties API was released,and never had any problems with that approach. imho, unless properties are reimplemented as a map that sits within the standard meta data, I can't see any reason to use them.

Comment: Agree, just discarded my changes and have reverted back to using the description field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum length for both keys and values should be 118 bytes, there is also a limitation about the maximum number of key/properties a file can have.

Comment: The maximum k/v pairs is 30.